# Unity Pixel Art Menu

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, pixel

As a beginner on Unity, I'm looking for a solution to a rather annoying problem. I've been through a lot of videos and articles, but I still can't solve it.

On a blank Scene, in a Canvas containing a Panel and an Image. I'm trying to display this image correctly. It is a pixel art image.

The problem is that it remains blurred and badly arranged according to the resolutions.

I try to find a way to display it correctly while keeping its pixel art aspect.

(I looked at the pixel perfect cameras, the stretch settings and others, I set the sprite parameters to Point and No compression and others. But nothing works).

I don't know how to propose different types of zoom according to the resolution and that the image doesn't blur

If someone has a little time, and can make me a scene just with his camera, and therefore the canvas, panel and image, with good setting so that I can understand my error. It would be a great help for me !

Thanks for reading !

[The background picture :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGspx.png)

Comment: There are many reasons why it might be blurry. First off, increase the size (resolution) of the image in your image editor. Next, experiment with the pixels per unit, generate mip maps, max size and compression setting in the inspector for the image. Also, build and run your app, sometimes the editor doesn't look like the final build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting the image in the assets and change the Resize algorithm to Point(no filter)
[image]

Comment: (I looked at the pixel perfect cameras, the stretch settings and others, I set the sprite parameters to Point and No compression and others. But nothing works).

Answer (score 0):

Hop, I found the solution thanks to this threed :

[Official - Pixel Perfect Preview Package](https://forum.unity.com/threads/pixel-perfect-preview-package.533433/)

By looking correctly at the settings apply. It came from the resizing of the Canvas and the management of the Camera.

Thanks for your messages !

And thanks to the author of the threed : [rustum](https://forum.unity.com/members/rustum.772304/) !